# Calculation in Javascript returns NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to calculate in Javascript. But the script is returning NaN.

I have tried to convert the data with `number`, `parseInt` and `parseFloat` but it was not succesfull.

Does someone know what is wrong with my script?

Here is my Javascript

```
$('[id^=neg_pos]').each( function( i, e) {
  var quantity = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  if ( quantity==='0') {

  } else if ( quantity==='1') {
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementsByName('price[]').value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementsByName('tax[]').value);

    var tv1 = num1 + num2;
    pos += tv1;

  } else {
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementsByName('price[]').value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementsByName('tax[]').value);

    var tv1 = num1 + num2;
    neg += tv1;
  }

document.getElementById('positive').value = pos.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('negative').value = neg.toFixed(2);

});
```

The textboxes `price[]` and `tax[]` are dynamic textboxes that are created in Javascript.

Here are the textboxes:
The first textboxes are created in HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="1">
<input type="text" name="tax[]" id="tax1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="1">
```

The other textboxes are created in Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_row', function(){
  count++;
  $('#total_item').val(count);
  var html_code = '';
  html_code += '<input type="text" name="price[]" id="price'+count+'" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="'+count+'">';
  html_code += '<input type="text" name="tax[]" id="tax'+count+'" onkeypress="return isNumber(event, this)" data-srno="'+count+'">';

  $('#test').append(html_code);
});
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements. So there is no `value` property.

Comment: @John Gabriel is correct. `document.getElementsByName('price[]')` will return a `NodeList` which has no `value` property. Did you mean `document.getElementsByName('price[]')[0].value`? (notice the `[0]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `document.getElementById()` instead, like so:

```
var num1 = Number(document.getElementsByName('price[]').value);
var num2 = Number(document.getElementsByName('tax[]').value);
```

The reason was you were trying to access the `value` property of the array returned by `getElementsByName`, which doesn't exist - you would have had to use `[0]` first, to access the element itself.